# PySpark: add a new field to a data frame Row element

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, row, pyspark

I have the following element:

```
a = Row(ts=1465326926253, myid=u'1234567', mytype=u'good')
```

The Row is of Spark data frame Row class. I want to append a new field to `a`, so that `a` would look like:

```
a = Row(ts=1465326926253, myid=u'1234567', mytype=u'good', name = u'john')
```

Answer (score 22):

Here is an updated answer that works.  First you have to create a dictionary then update the dict and then write it out to a pyspark Row.

Code is as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

#Creating the pysql row
row = Row(field1=12345, field2=0.0123, field3=u'Last Field')

#Convert to python dict
temp = row.asDict()

#Do whatever you want to the dict. Like adding a new field or etc.
temp["field4"] = "it worked!"

# Save or output the row to a pyspark rdd
output = Row(**temp)

#How it looks
output

In [1]:
Row(field1=12345, field2=0.0123, field3=u'Last Field', field4='it worked!')
```

Comment: YOU DA REAL MVP

Comment: With this solution keeping the same order of columns in the new row is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot add new field to the `Row`. [`Row` is a subclass of `tuple`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4f1e38649ebc7710850b7c40e6fb355775e7bb7f/python/pyspark/sql/types.py#L1405)

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

issubclass(Row, tuple)
## True

isinstance(Row(), tuple)
## True
```

and Python `tuples` are immutable. All you can do is create a new one:

```
row = Row(ts=1465326926253, myid=u'1234567', mytype=u'good') 

# In legacy Python: Row(name=u"john", **row.asDict())
Row(**row.asDict(), name=u"john") 
## Row(myid='1234567', mytype='good', name='john', ts=1465326926253)
```

Please note that `Row` keeps it fields sorted by name.