# pyspark add new row to dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to add a new row to dataframe but cant.

my code:

```
newRow = Row(id='ID123')
newDF= df.insertInto(newRow)
 or 
newDF= df.union(newRow)
```

errors:

```
AttributeError: _jdf

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'insertInto'
```

Comment: This might be something you are looking for. Try `from pyspark.sql import Row`, create a dictionary and then update the dictionary. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801691/pyspark-add-a-new-field-to-a-data-frame-row-element

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try: ([Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html))

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
newDf = sc.parallelize([Row(id='ID123')]).toDF()
newDF.show()
```

Comment: it creating newDF rather than adding new

Comment: dataframes like RDD's are immutable and hence a new once is always created based on any action.

Comment: I'm confused. Where is the original df in this response? Not seeing how this answers the original question.

Comment: This is not a helpful answer. There is no indication that a dataFrame is being appended to. Alkesh Mahajan's answer is correct.

Answer (score 20):

Simple way to add row in dataframe using pyspark

```
newRow = spark.createDataFrame([(15,'Alk','Dhl')])
df = df.union(newRow)
df.show()
```

Answer (score -6):

Operation like is completely useless in practice.  Spark `DataFrame` is a data structure designed for bulk analytical jobs. It is not intended for fine grained updates.

Although you can create single row `DataFrame` ([as shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47556546/8371915) by [i-n-n-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6626093/i-n-n-m)) and `union` it won't scale and won't truly distribute the data - Spark will have to keep local copy of the data, and execution plan will grow linearly with the number of inserted objects.

Please consider using proper database instead.

Comment: I needed it just for testing.